Why is completeness (as in Gödel completeness theorem) a desirable feature?
When justifying the dominance of first-order theory, an argument that is often made is that it is complete (as shown by Gödel).
This means that a theory formulated in first-order logic has a model if and only if it is consistent.
Equivalently, it means that a proposition (of such a theory) is a theorem if and only if it is true in every model of the theory.
I understand that, still I fail to see what completeness brings concretely.
Are there real advantages of completeness when dealing with a theory, either from the mathematical, computational or philosophical point of view?

(Someone should remove that extraneous "e" from the "goedel" tag)

A complete proof system vaptures our natural understanding of deduction, that meas that the logical engine tracks faithfully the concept of logical consequence, that in turn formalizes our natural understanding of consequence.

The "equivalence" of two very different views of "formality" the syntactical manipulation of symbols, and the truth preservation under every possible interpretation of the non-logical terms means that we have captured a deep and stable concept.

There is a powerful theorem, which is the basis for indepedence results which in practice, its applications  rely on a theory being consistant iff it has a model. Theorem: Let T be a Theory, T ⊬ σ iff T ∪ {¬σ} is consistsnt. With Gödels proof it is sufficient to show that T ∪ {¬σ} has a model. This is how we show that A theory cannot prove something. Its how we showed that Euclids 5th is independnet of the other Euclidean axioms

Philosphically, it says that if we can prove something, then it is true in every interpretation. It basically says our synthetic notion of proof satisfies properties that we intuitevly think a proof should have. thst if ae prove something, it doesnt matter jow we interpret the syntax, what we proved still holds. Its true under any interpretation. In some sense, it captures the idea that, theorems should be "objective truths"

@MichaelCarey What you are describing is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness. Completeness is essentially about the "P is true in every model of the theory" => "P is a theorem" way.

@Weier you are right. I should add that it is both soundness and completeness which made FOL attractive. Completeness geta more focus in FOL vecause proving Soundness is relatively trivial and easy to do

What does it even mean to say that an inconsistent theory has a model?

@MichaelCarey: IMHO it's more that soundness is considered table stakes (an unsound deductive system is completely worthless unless it is paraconsistent, and that has its own issues, so almost any system that anyone wants to use for serious purposes will be sound).

Because compactness easily follows, and compactness allows the construction of many, many easy counterexamples

@Weier it's not extraneous. His name was Gödel and the usual convention for German names (and words more generally) is that where the umlaut is unavailable (as in the tags) it should be replaced with a following e i.e. Goedel.

Right, "Godel" would just be wrong.

Someone should put the missing "e" into the "godels-incompleteness-theorem" tag.

Completeness usually uncritically conceived as perfection is certainly a strong human desire, if the theory of PA were complete, then either Goldbach's conjecture or its negation would be assured to be provable. Yet tautologies or their negations of the complete logics are indeed provable...

@DoubleKnot you seem to be referring to the completeness as expressed in Gödel's incompleteness theorem, not his completeness theorem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(logic)#Forms_of_completeness)

We could have a complete alphabet which worked across all languages, and then stop arguing about spelling.

@Weier I saw you had Gödel's incompleteness theorem tag originally and now is gone. Indeed your question is about semantic completeness and its desirability is touched by my comment about tautologies. However, syntactic negation completeness addressed by Gödel's incompleteness theorems is a more desirable feature of a theory and leads to a subtly different but even more desirable feature called decidability in a computably enumerable fashion. Not all semantically and syntactically complete theories are decidable...

@Weier: Have you understood my answer?

If you have a set A of axioms, which you assume to be true, you would of course be interested in all the sentences that are necessarily true given A. On the surface, this is difficult to know because it involves all possible models of A, which may include (very) uncountably many models. But look! The semantic-completeness theorems for a deductive system for FOL implies that you can in fact (within that system) prove any such sentence. So if A is computably enumerable (which is always the case for practical formal systems), then the set of all sentences that are true in every model of A is also computably enumerable! We can write a computer program that would eventually generate all these sentences and no others!

@DikranMarsupial The hard part arises when it is difficult to prove whether any given sentence is provable or not.  As a practical matter, lots of philosophical topics run into self-referential patterns due to the concept behind the word "I."  That being said, it's absolutely standard practice to try to come up with a sub model (a smaller model that is entailed by the larger one) with better properties (such as being complete because you removed all of the pesky statements).

@DikranMarsupial: We must have that we can only deduce true statements from true assumptions. We hope that we can deduce all statements that are necessarily true given the assumptions. This has absolutely nothing to do with self-reference. Do not blindly assume that semantic-completeness is related to syntactic-completeness.

@DikranMarsupial: If it's not in terms that you can appreciate, then you need to do a proper study of FOL. Let me know your mathematical background and I can give you recommended references to work through that are suitable for your current level.

@‍Dikran: Yes, learn it or leave it. (All mathematics, discrete or not, is based on FOL. PL is too impoverished.)

The completeness of a formal system is very desirable because it ensures that semantic truth (truth in all models, all interpretations) is fully captured by syntactic validity (provability, derivability inside the system, based on its axioms and rules). In a complete formal system every semantically true statement can in principle be proven. If we enumerate, in a systematic, mechanical (purely syntactic) way all the provable theorems of the system, we will enumerate all expressible truths of that system. -- We'd like to be able to know whether we found all semantic truths, whether we have a general, "simple" method of doing so; and if possible, we'd like to be able to generate all of them in a purely mechanical way. Completeness gives us that.

From Wikipedia:
Gödel's original formulation

The completeness theorem says that if a formula is logically valid then there is a finite deduction (a formal proof) of the formula.


Thus, the deductive system is "complete" in the sense that no additional inference rules are required to prove all the logically valid formulae. A converse to completeness is soundness, the fact that only logically valid formulae are provable in the deductive system. Together with soundness (whose verification is easy), this theorem implies that a formula is logically valid if and only if it is the conclusion of a formal deduction

Any statement in the language of first order predicate logic has a semantically equivalent statement formulatable in the propositional calculus.  Rosser's system RS for the propositional calculus is complete, in the sense that all tautologies are theorems of RS.  Since any logically valid formula is equivalent in meaning to a tautology, the proof that RS is complete simultaneously proves FOL is complete. Thus, you can bypass Godel's difficult proof of the completeness of a first order function calculus, by first proving FOL is reducible to the propositional calculus.
The reason completeness is desirable, is so you know your system, RS, or Hilbert Ackerman HA, or whatever, has enough axioms and underived rules of inference to prove all tautologies as theorems of the system.

That's what I also think is the conclusion of Gödel's proof. However, if I may say so, and I'm sure someone like yourself, who's probably done tons of formal proofs using predicate logic, must've noticed - some proofs are, how shall I put it?, too long. Maybe if we added some more inference rules, we can shorten the distance, as it were, between premises and conclusion, oui?

@Hudjefa, of course you can shorten the proofs, but my point is simply Godel's, and Leon Henkins for that matter, proof of completeness can be dispensed with.  Once you prove the propositional calculus is complete you are done.  And Henkin's proof is hard to follow.

How would you answer the OP's query. What does completeness have to offer? As far as I'm concerned, I'm quite happy to have a system that ensures all valid formulae/arguments are derivable from a set of inference rules.

First order logic is not reducible to the propositional calculus.

@Bumble, I already convinced myself it is, by defining for all x [p(x)]= p(x1)&P(x2)&...., so how did you prove first order logic isn't reducible to the propositional calculus?  Surely you have a proof to back up your assertion.

You can consult any textbook on logic. Propositional logic and quantifier logic are quite different. Propositional logic is decidable; quantifier logic is not. Representing a universally quantified sentence as a conjunction and an existentially quantified sentence as a disjunction does not work if the domain is infinite.

@Bumble, I wrote a text on logic and my proof is in there.  If they are quite different, as you say, then you should be able to provide a counter example to my statement that every first order logical statement has a semantically equivalent statement in the propositional calculus.  Where's your counter example?

Every natural number has a successor.

@Bumble, that's not good enough, it's not a pure first order logical statement.  I'm looking for something like this: For all x P(x) not equivalent to P(x1)&P(x2)&P(x3)&..., because such and such.  It is my position that they are equivalent.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

If I  remember  right John Baldwin pointed the following: If    you want to prove an identity  e.g $  \forall x \forall  (x+y)^2 =   x^2 + 2xy + y^2  $    you have to substitute all possible values of the  variables to verify the identity. In the case of an infinite set this is impossible, the alternative is to  resort to a proof   which is of finite length.  So you need  proofs to   represent  validities somehow. The above remark  IMHO   shows a  weakenss of inifinitary  arguments   even in simple cases as identities.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
